# We haven't seen a dog since we sat down here

Tags: grammar

> We haven't seen a dog since we sat down here.

In the sentence above, what does *sat down* mean? Does it mean the short action of *sitting down from a standing position* or the *continuous action of sitting*?

Comment: Can you see a difference between "since we sat down here"  and "since we've been sitting here"?

Comment: You would need some context to be sure. It could be either.

Comment: @None: I guess they mean the same in my original sentence. So, I suspect that *since I sat down here* means *since I began to sit here*. Is it right?

Comment: @Dan: if it means the continuous sitting, it's self-contradictory. You can't say "here", because you're no longer in the place. You should say "there".

Comment: While still sitting and remarking on the lack of dogs. Or, hours later, passing by the place they sat and rested on the hike out, and remarking on the lack of dogs on the whole hike. You need context.

Comment: For your first possibility, I think *sat down* means the beginning of sitting. For your second possibility, I think it means the continuous sitting. Yes, I agree we need contexts to determine its exact meaning. Either is possible.

Comment: Yes, *since I sat down here* means *since I began to sit here*, it refers to the action of sitting down. *Sit down* implies a movement. *Sit* just refers to the position.